# Logstash creating pipelines from Kafka not working

Tags: elasticsearch, apache-kafka, logstash

I am trying to get data from Kafka topic to run into ELK-stack with Logstash but can't get the data moving.

I edited the logstash.conf to following:

```
input {
        tcp {
            port => 5000
        }
        kafka {
            bootstrap_servers => "broker:29092"
            topics => ["PLACES_ROWKEY"]
        }
}

## Add your filters / logstash plugins configuration here

output {
        elasticsearch {
                hosts => ["elasticsearch:9200"]
                user => "elastic"
                password => "changeme"
                index => "from_logstash"
        }
}
```

Im running this setup in Docker if it matters (broker is the hostname for the Kafka broker container). I restart the Logstash but cant see any new indices in elasticsearch

Comment: If you're running it in Docker can you share your Docker Compose? Have you looked at using Kafka Connect Elasticsearch sink?

Comment: @Robin Moffat  I have been using connect sinks for most part but i need to visualize data into burndown charts and in Kibana only Timelion can do that and for it i need the index to have a timestamp column. When i sink from Kafka, i need to make the index pattern to have the scripted field as timestamp column. I can compose file when i get back on laptop

Comment: Out of interest, what is the scripted column? Perhaps you could do it with Single Message Transform as part of the Connect sink

Comment: Scripted column is a way in Kibana to transform values while making them part of index pattern and usable for visualizations. I havent heard of Single message Transform esrlier, I'll check it out!

Comment: I meant what *is* the scripted column that you've having to build in ES? Maybe I can suggest how to do it in Single Message Transform

Comment: Oh hahah oops. Im transforming epoch timestamp into a proper timestamp. I noticed there is TimestampConverter in SMT  catalog. I could try making that work tomorrow.

Comment: Yep, `TimestampConverter` will do that. Feel free to post a new SO question if you get stuck :)

Comment: Tomorrow evening ill have time to try it out. Thanks a lot Robin! You saved me once again from hours of frustration :)